# SSH and VPN split tunneling Windows 2012 server

Tags: windows, ssh, split, vpn, tunnel

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a Windows Server 2012R2 running Bitvise SSH server, for the sake of simplicity it has only one ethernet card. SSH listens to 192.168.1.115 port 22.

When the server is connected to the internet with VPN (NordVPN client > I cannot edit config) the SSH connection is no longer working. I believe this is very normal as the VPN changes the gateway and routes all, including SSH, packages through it.

I was hoping it is possible to simply edit the routing table or similar so that all SSH packages on 192.168.1.115 port 22 are routed to the original gateway (the gateway before VPN is connected so to speak) and that all other are routed via the VPN gateway.

Alas, I have no idea how to start with this split tunneling. Maybe there are tools or other solution for this? I have search high and low but did not find an easy answer.

Looking really forward to your expertise. Thank you.

With best regards,

ShadowHunter

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should ask questions like this on [su] or maybe [sf].

Comment: Appolgies, you are right. Thank you.